# Connectionstring mdf file in superior folder

Tags: c#, connection-string, sql-server-2008-express, mdf

I´ve got the following connectionstring:

```
string connectionstr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;" + "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\..\\..\\Datenbank\\FarmersCalc.mdf;" + "Integrated Security=True;" + "User Instance=true;";
```

As i know, `|DataDirectory|` is the `/bin/debug`- folder. 
The mdf file is in the folder `Datenbank`, that is for sure in the folder that I typed in in the connection string.

It seems, as `..\\` would not work. 
Does anybody have a solution for that problem?

Comment: What is the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: I believe |DataDirectory| refers to the "App_Data" folder beneath the project folder.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# " and such. that's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2):

You could just calculate the dir using the following code.

```
//these two lines get the executable's directory
Uri u = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(u.LocalPath));

//this goes up two directories and combines that directory with the rest
//of the path to the file
string path = Path.Combine(d.Parent.Parent.FullName, @"Datenbank\FarmersCalc.mdf;");
Console.WriteLine(path);
```

Comment: What version of csharp are you using?  You need to include the `System.IO` and `System.Reflection` namespaces for this to work, obviously.  I doubt that's the problem, just putting it out there.